# agg condition : keyword can't be an expression with Pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I am using pyspark to reate a dataframe which calculates the sum of  "montant" when the value of the column "isfraud" ==1  .

But I get this error :

> File "", line 5
>       when(col("isFraud") =1, sum("montant"))
>           ^ SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression

Here the code :

```
 CNP_df_fraude= (tx_wd_df
                 #.filter("isFraude =='1'").filter("POS_Card_Presence =='CardNotPresent'")
                 .groupBy("POS_Cardholder_Presence")
                 .agg(
                     when(col("isFraud") =1, sum("montant"))
                 )
                )
```

Any idea please?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just put when() inside sum():

```
CNP_df_fraude= (tx_wd_df
            .groupBy("POS_Cardholder_Presence")
            .agg(
                 sum(when(col("isFraud")==1, col("montant")).otherwise(0))
             )
            )
```

Comment: thanks , but I got this error : NameError: name 'when' is not defined"

Comment: @Nasri, you need to import all three functions: `from pyspark.sql.functions import when, col, sum`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `when()` inside the `.agg()` function.

You could however try:

```py
 CNP_df_fraude= tx_wd_df.filter(F.col("isFraud") == 1)
                .groupBy("POS_Cardholder_Presence")
                .sum("montant")
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't like to filter "isfraud"==1